# Object's ref count

Tags: javascript, destructor

Seeing that there's no destructor in javascript I am wondering if there's any hack to intercept when an object reaches zero references. Practically it would be almost as useful as having a destructor.

**Edit:**
Essentially what I miss is a way to implement RAII and variations of the concept: This is a simplification of the idea, perhaps mutexes are not the most typical situation in js but to get the idea:

```
class MutexLocker{
    theMutex:Mutex;
    constructor(mutex){
        mutex.lock();
    }
    refCountZero(){
        this.theMutex.release();
    }
}
let someMutex=new Mutex;
function whatever(){
    let ml=new MutexLocker(someMutex);
    try{
        ...
    }

    // at exit on this function on any case including exceptions ml would reach zero and release the mutex
}
```

Comment: You can always count references yourself. No, there's no builtin to do that.

Comment: Is there any context in which you need a JS destructor, other than hypothetical purposes?

Comment: Please specify a specific use-case that you want to implement using destructor, otherwise this question seems to be too broad to answer as a destructor could be achieving multiple things in different platforms.

Comment: @gurvinder372  I've edited with a case to illustrate the need.